# Xcode Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i tried to compile by iphone app in xcode and i got this

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

how do i get rid of it? i dont plan on selling anything on the app store just yet cause i just started with objective-c. do i have to register with the dev netwrok even though? there has to be a way around it. its a dumb thing..

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to use an actual device you can simply switch to using the simulator

```
Project -> Active SDK -> iPhone Simulator
```

Otherwise you'll be needing a developer certificate from Apple